# Validate Array Json Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a select and **rowData[]** when I click on the Add button, I add the name and the value on a table where I use the function **.push** for add the data into a JSON array, but I don't want to add duplicates values.

```
 addItem () {

    var equipos_torneo = {
      id_torneo: this.id_torneo,
      id_equipo: this.id_equipo,
      nombre_equipo: nombre_team,
    }

    this.rowData.push(equipos_torneo)
    console.log(equipos_torneo.id_equipo)
  },

}
```

Table:

```
   <tbody>
        <tr
          v-for="item in rowData"
          :key="item.id_torneo"
        >
          <td>{{ item.id_torneo }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.id_equipo }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.nombre_equipo }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Which property do you want to be unique in the array?  Is it `id_torneo`? Or another, or all of them?

Comment: @danh In that case, id_equipo

Comment: use [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: You can use `this.rowData.findIndex(e => e.id_equipo === equipos_torneo.id_equipo)` in order to find out if an array already has an object in it with the same `id_equipo` property. If this function returns `-1`, then you can push the new item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question to be asking how to prevent a push of an object that has duplicate value(s) in the array.  Just find out (with `find`) before pushing.

```
addItem() {
  let equipos_torneo = {
    id_torneo: this.id_torneo,
    id_equipo: this.id_equipo,
    nombre_equipo: nombre_team,
  };
  let exists = this.rowData.find(el => el.id_equipo === equipos_torneo.id_equipo);
  if (!exists) this.rowData.push(equipos_torneo);
}
```

Comment: Semantically, [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be a better choice here, but otherwise that is the right answer.

Comment: @aweebit, aren't the semantics equivalent?  If there aren't some then there isn't one.  If there isn't one, then there aren't some.

Comment: the code works the same, I just meant that `some()` is exactly there for the purpose of checking if an item satisfying certain criteria exists in an array, and so it is better suited for this use case by its meaning. Maybe I used the word

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether there is any *similar* value before pushing to **rowData[]**.

I suggest something like this:

```
addItem(){
let duplicates=[]
var equipos_torneo = {
  id_torneo: this.id_torneo,
  id_equipo: this.id_equipo,
  nombre_equipo: nombre_team,
}
this.rowData.forEach((element, index)=>{
    if(element.id_torneo===equipos_torneo.id_torneo){
        duplicates.push(index)
  }
    else if(element.id_equipo===equipos_torneo.id_equipo){
        duplicates.push(index)
  }
    else if(element.nombre_equipo===equipos_torneo.nombre_equipo){
        duplicates.push(index)
  }
    else{
        this.rowData.push(equipos_torneo)
  }
})
}
```

this way you only push to **rowData[]** only if there are no duplicated.
If there are any duplicates, you will find them in **duplicates[]**